# Rotate a view continously using Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I am learning `Canvas` and I am trying to implement using it. Is there an easy way to `rotate` a **line or Rect** continuosly.

**ArcView.java**

```
public class ArcView extends View {
    private Paint linePaint;
    private float angle = 45f;
    private float increment = 0.01f;

    private float canvasWidth,canvasHeight;
    private float xo,yo;

    public ArcView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initVals();
    }

    public ArcView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initVals();
    }

    public ArcView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initVals();
    }

    private void initVals(){

        setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
        //setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.process_dafault);
        //setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.process_dafault));

        linePaint = new Paint();
        linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        linePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        linePaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        linePaint.setStrokeWidth(15);

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        canvasWidth = getWidth();
        canvasHeight = getHeight();
        xo = canvasWidth / 2f;
        yo = canvasHeight / 2f;
        canvas.translate(xo, yo);


        for (int x = 0; x < 360; x += 45) {
            canvas.rotate(45f);
            canvas.drawLine(0f, 0f, 200f, 200f, linePaint);
        }

        /*for(int index = 0 ; index < 100 ; index++){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    canvas.save();
                    canvas.rotate(15f);
                    canvas.drawLine(0f,0f,200f,200f,linePaint);
                    canvas.restore();
                }
            },200);
            }*/

    }
}
```

I want to draw a circle which animates in **Polar Coordinates** with a `radius`.For now I am trying this with line.

First of all I translate my canvas to center using.

```
 canvas.translate(xo, yo);
```

then

I wanna find x and y polor coordinates using given formula

```
x = Radius * Math.cos(theta);
y = Radius * Math.sin(theta);
```

then draw line or circle at that point.

```
canvas.drawLine(0f, 0f, x, y, linePaint);
```

Comment: use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`, or if you want to rotate it all the time, use `TimeAnimator` wich has no duration concept

Comment: as i see in your code: `"for(int index = 0 ; index < 100 ; index++)"` you dont need infinite animation, so just use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: pskink I apologize for not responding. Right now ,Unfortunately I don't have system to test the code. But one thing I need to ask can we Animate line or rect created by canvas using ValueAnimator /ObjectAnimator

Comment: `But one thing I need to ask can we Animate line or rect created by canvas using ValueAnimator /ObjectAnimator `  - this is what they are for

Comment: pskink share your code to animate a circle or line using canvas

Comment: did you try any of them? i mean ValueAnimator or ObjectAnimator ?

Comment: Not yet. But I'll try and let you know

Comment: ok so try [this](http://pastebin.com/A0QcKMYt) and next time read some more about animators

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to rotate your **line** continuously.

```
public class ArcView extends View {
    private Paint linePaint;
    private float angle = 45f;
    private float increment = 0.01f;

    private float canvasWidth, canvasHeight;
    private float xo, yo;
    private float degreeToRotate = 0f;

    public ArcView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initVals();
    }

    public ArcView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initVals();
    }

    public ArcView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initVals();
    }

    private void initVals() {

        setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
        //setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.process_dafault);
        //setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.process_dafault));

        linePaint = new Paint();
        linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        linePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        linePaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        linePaint.setStrokeWidth(15);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (degreeToRotate == -1) return;

        Log.d("alex.hong", "draw with degree = " + degreeToRotate);
        canvasWidth = getWidth();
        canvasHeight = getHeight();
        xo = canvasWidth / 2f;
        yo = canvasHeight / 2f;

        canvas.translate(xo, yo);
        canvas.rotate(degreeToRotate);
        canvas.drawLine(0f, 0f, 200f, 200f, linePaint);
    }

    public void startAnim() {
        new Rotate360Task().execute();
    }

    class Rotate360Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Float, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            float degree = 0f;
            while (degree <= 360f) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                publishProgress(degree);
                degree += 0.5f;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            degreeToRotate = values[0];
            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

When you want to rotate, such as click a button or something else. call method `startAnim()` then observe.

Hope it help!